# Finding top 3 values along with their headers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to be able to look at two rows and retrieve the top 3 highest values(found in row 2) along with their header(found in row 1). Here is what I have:
[image]

I am using the Large formula to retrieve the values, however it only brings the value. Is there a way for me to also retrieve its header? If so how?
Thank you in advance!
UPDATE: I just attempted to use the Lookup formula doing, "=LOOKUP(A7,A2:F2,A1:F1)" however it returned Value 6 instead of value 4, same with other values.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In A6 try

```
=transpose(array_constrain(sort(transpose(A1:G2), 2, 0), 3, 2))
```

and see if that works?

[image]